# I want center layout be on top of right layout in android

Tags: android, xml

I want my center layout be on top of right layout.
I should use linear to have weight and when I add margin the center layout become under right layout.but I want the center to be on top.is there any solution?

[image]

that is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Layout xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your activity `onCreate()` method, do this

```
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(findViewById(R.id.second), 1);
```